# How do I target the MSS value in a TCP packet using BPF

Tags: iptables, bpf

I am learning BPF and converting some iptables rules to BPF bytcode. I am primarily using the nfbpf_compile application to do this, rather than trying to write C or Assembler. I am having a lot of luck but the syntax of one rule is escaping me.

I'd like to drop packets with the syn flag set that is **also** missing an MSS value. In iptables the MSS is targetted with `--tcp-option 2`. I know that MSS is in the TCP options that start at byte 22 of the TCP packet, and MSS is 'kind' 2. I am able to filter the MSS by using `tcp[22:2]==$NUMBER` in BPF syntax. However, what I want to do is target SYN packets where the MSS is missing entirely.

I have tried every variant of "null" I can think of but am having no luck.

Does anyone know the equivalent of iptables `! --tcp-option 2` in BPF syntax?

An example of something I have tried:

```
$ ./nfbpf_compile RAW 'tcp[22:2]==0x0'  (I know this won't work..it's an example)
12,48 0 0 0,84 0 0 240,21 0 8 64,48 0 0 9,21 0 6 6,40 0 0 6,69 4 0 8191,177 0 0 0,72 0 0 22,21 0 1 0,6 0 0 65535,6 0 0 0

# iptables -I INPUT -m bpf --bytecode '12,48 0 0 0,84 0 0 240,21 0 8 64,48 0 0 9,21 0 6 6,40 0 0 6,69 4 0 8191,177 0 0 0,72 0 0 22,21 0 1 0,6 0 0 65535,6 0 0 0
' -j DROP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** If you know there are only 0 or 1 TCP options, or if you know the MSS option is always the first option, then you can use the following filter:

```
tcp && (tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn) && ((((tcp[12] & 0xf0) >> 2) < 21) || tcp[20] != 2)
```

If you don't know this (there are several TCP options and the MSS option may be any of them), which is generally the case, I don't think it's possible to express a matching filter with nfbpf_compile's syntax. In that case, I would recommend writing a C program and loading it with [`-m bpf --object-pinned /path/to/pinned/bpf`](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html).

---

**Let me explain the above filter first.** You have two cases to match: 1) there is no TCP option or 2) the first TCP option is not the MSS:

- `tcp[12] & 0xf0` extracts the data offset field from the TCP header, i.e., the number of 32bit word in the TCP header.
- `(tcp[12] & 0xf0) >> 2` multiplies this by 4 to get the number of bytes.
- If you have less than 21 bytes in your TCP header, then you know there are no TCP options.
- `tcp[20] != 2` checks that the Option-Kind field of the first TCP option (starts at offset 20) is not 2, the Option-Kind for MSS.

**Why is the general case harder to match?** TCP options have a variable length (depending on their Option-Kind) and there is a variable, bounded number of TCP options. Say you want to extend the above filter to match on the second TCP option. You first need to know where that option starts; the first option has a variable length so this is not a fixed offset.

With cBPF (the BPF bytecode emitted by nfbpf_compile), you might be able to express that by storing the current option offset in the X register and then loading a byte into register A with the 2nd addressing mode (see [the Linux documentation, `BPF engine and instruction set`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt)). However, I do not think you can do this with the limited nfbpf_compile syntax (assuming it's the same syntax as tcpdump's).